# "Chrome extension throws CRX file Error "CRX_REQUIRD_PROOF_MISSING"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crx

I have Chrome extension and create the `crx` file using developer mode. I uploaded the `crx` file to some internal url (www.xyz.com/internal.crx).

Whenever i am trying to install the extension with URL (not in developer mode) it is throwing error Package is invalid:

> CRX_REQUIRD_PROOF_MISSING

Same `CRX` file i used in developer mode with drag and drop and it's working fine. Please help to solve the problem with URL downloading and installing extension internally.

Comment: It means your manifest.json is missing the `"key"` entry or the hashsum in crx header doesn't match that key.

Comment: I created the package with chrome pack extension itself. Please let me know how can i fix the issue.

Comment: My comment contains two reasons and you didn't reply to the first one.

Comment: I have pem file generated while creating the extension pack. I have added same in mainfeast.json 'key'. Let me know if i need to do any update on same.

Comment: It should be `manifest.json`, not `mainfeast.json`. To generate the `"key"` use https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/ - upload your extension, then copy the value from devtools console.

Comment: I used below url and get the same 'key' value and added in manifest.json. But still facing same issue Package is invalid:CRX_REQUIRD_PROOF_MISSING
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key

Comment: @wOxxOm I did not get any solution. Please let me know if anything else missing from my end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In recent versions of Chrome only CRX3 format is supported:

> Instructions for Repackaging
>   Please see the following [article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/linux_hosting#packaging) for detailed instructions on how to repackage Chrome apps and extensions into the CRX3 format.
>
> If you use an open source library to build extensions please verify CRX3 support with that vendor. In addition you can use https://crx-checker.appspot.com  to check the version of your extension and let your vendor know.
>
> If you are unable to repackage or cannot use the CRX3 format, you can enable the [ExtensionAllowInsecureUpdates](https://chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionAllowInsecureUpdates) policy.  Note that this is only a temporary workaround, all extensions must move to the CRX3 format!
>
> M76 (July 2019)
>   By default, CRX2 will be disabled and everyone should move to CRX3. 
>   As a temporary workaround, [ExtensionAllowInsecureUpdates](https://chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionAllowInsecureUpdates) can be used to re-enable CRX2.

(from https://www.chromium.org/crx2-deprecation)

Your options are:

- Repack the extension in CRX3 format in some way or another, for example with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crx3) npm package.
- Use one of the other suggested solutions above

Answer (score 8):

In Chrome 75 it seems impossible to add an extension manually. Even if you manage to drag and drop it to `chrome://extensions/`page - chrome will block it from use.
The only way of distribution now seems to be only through the Chrome Web Store.
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2811969

Also see here: https://github.com/ahwayakchih/crx3#crx_required_proof_missing

Comment: Just FYI when using selenium, it is working to add local extensions. Installing in UI does not work.

Comment: So if you get a .zip extension, you can unzip it and then install it ("Load unpacked")  -  but if it's a crx, then it's not allowed?  Seriously this is utterly ridiculous.

Comment: Switched to Chromium, some builds allow installing local extensions. https://chromium.woolyss.com

Answer (score 7):

As of December 2020.
Only 4 possible option to install extension.

1. Get a signed CRX file from Google web store.
2. Use `Chromium` to install CRX file in developer mode.
3. Import extension's directory as unpacked extension.
4. Modify/Configure ExtensionSettings policy as in documented [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9867568?hl=en).

I preferred option 2, as I am a private person. And option 4 in enterprise settings.

In some cases it is not advisable or not feasible to submit the browser extension for Google certification.