# How to add chrome extension with Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension

I tried like this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

but in new versions of Chrome CRX is not accepted and you need to set CRX3

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: CRX verification failed to parse extension header. Chrome supports only CRX3 format. Does the extension need to be updated?
```

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 81.0.4044.138

Answer (score 0):

With chrome version 75 and above, CRX3 extension packing is enforced. You need to repackage your .crx extension to .crx3. Refer [this SO answer on repackaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599518/5570477)